# Computing $\mathbb{C}[x,y]^G$ or $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]^G$ where $G$ is a finite subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory, matrices, finite-groups, invariant-theory

My question is related to this link: [Ring of Invariant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39117/ring-of-invariant)

---

$\mathbf{Question \;1}$. Let 
$$
A = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1& 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right). 
$$
Then $C= \langle A\rangle$ is a cyclic, finite group of order $4$.

Suppose $A$ acts on $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ linearly.

> Then what is the subring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]^C$ of invariant functions in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$? What is the basic strategy?

Note that 
$$
C = \left\{ 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1& 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right), 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0 \\
0& -1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right),
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
-1& 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right),
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
\right\}. 
$$

---

$\mathbf{Question \;2}$. Now, suppose the dihedral group $D_6 = \langle \rho, \psi : \rho^6 = \psi^2 =e,\psi \rho\psi^{-1}=\rho^{-1} \rangle$ acts on $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$, with the action defined by the matrices 
$$ 
\rho = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1/2 & -\sqrt{3}/2 & 0 \\ 
-\sqrt{3}/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) 
 \mbox{ and }
\psi = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}  
1 & 0  & 0 \\
0 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}\right). 
$$

> Then what is $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]^{D_6}$?

---

> $\mathbf{Question \;3}$. What is the general strategy, if we have something like the subgroup generated by $B$ and $-B$ in $GL_3(\mathbb{C})$ acting on a polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ of only two variables, where 
>   $$
> B = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> 1 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 
> 0 & 0& 1 \\ 
> \end{array} \right)? 
> $$

Comment: The basic strategy I'm aware of is to write down some invariant polynomials and then use Molien's theorem to check that you've found a set of generators.

Comment: I agree with Qiaochu.  There is a very nice book which treats this material: Mara Neusel's *Invariant Theory*.  See e.g. http://www.amazon.com/Invariant-Theory-Student-Mathematical-Library/dp/0821841327

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thanks for the reply! I studied group theory but I just realized that I've never worked with finite groups acting on a polynomial ring before. That's why I'm asking these questions. And I just learned how to "ping" people, and I think you're supposed to ping one person at a time.